# JPQL (with Hibernate) adding fields to query, which are not desired

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a following entity structure.

```
Venue -- n:1 -- Schedule -- 1:n -- Event
```

I have a query to get counts of all schedule in Venues:

```
SELECT v, count(s.event) FROM Venue v 
LEFT JOIN i.schedule s 
GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY count(s.event) asc;
```

The problem is that this query will never output venues, that have zero events. The problem is with Hibernate, which generates following:

```
select ..., count(schedule4_.event_id) as col_7_0_ 
from Venue venue0_ 
left outer join event_schedule schedule4_ on venue0_.id=schedule4_.venue_id, 
  Event event5_
where schedule4_.event_id=event5_.id and ...
```

You can see, that Hibernate tries to join `Event` on `Schedule` even though I did not request that. Obviously if the `Schedule` does not exist, joining `Event` does not make any sense.

(I simpified the query, if there is some typo, it should not have any impact on the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following query:

```
select v.id, count(e.id) from Venue v 
left join v.schedule s 
left join s.events e
group by v.id order by count(e.id) asc;
```

Comment: I've already tried - it just adds `left outer join Event event5_ on schedule4_.event_id=event5_.id, Event event6_`, but the rest of the query is the same.

Comment: Make sure you replace `count(s.event)` by `count(e.id)` as shown above. I don't see why it would add this additional table in the from clause if you don't use any implicit join in the query.